# Grails jaxrs How to add my own method/url to respond a random element

Tags: rest, url, grails, jax-rs

I'm looking for a solution to the following approach:
I implemented a REST Webservice in Grails 2.3.8 and jaxrs 0.10. Now I should have an method that will give me a random element from my object list. Is that possible?

I tried to add a method in the CollectionResource-Class so I can call //localhost:8080/myproject/api/report/rand

```
@Path('/api/report')
@Consumes(['application/json'])
@Produces(['application/json'])
class ReportCollectionResource {

def reportResourceService

   @GET
   @Path('/rand')
   Response readRandom() {
     ok alpResourceService.readRandom()
   }
}
```

And I added in the ReportResourceService a method that gives a random Report:

```
Private Randon random = new Random()
def readRandom() {
  def alps = Alp.list()
  alps[random.nextInt(alps.size())]
}
```

But now when I call the URL "localhost:8080/myproject/api/report/rand" I get an HTTP Status 405 - Method not allowed Error.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or what I've missing?
Thanks a lot.